# The Field "$_id" must be an accumulator object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to `group` some documents within mongoDB, right after a `$match` stage like this:

```
db.trips.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
      "Stop Time": {
        "$lt": "31.07.2013 23:59"
      }
    }
  },
    {   "$group": {
          "$_id": { "Start": "$Start", "End": "$End" },
    }
  }]
```

However I am getting the following error:

> "The field '$_id' must be an accumulator object"

Why does this error show up, and why does it only show up when I include the match stage? Without the match stage, it works just fine.

Comment: $_id means you want to use the value of the _id field i don't think this is possible in this situation

Comment: @UlugToprak Yes that's it ... typo.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**$_id** is not an accumulator function it should be **_id**

Comment: Can it be named something else besides _id?