# MongoDB Aggregation - $group after $lookup + $unwind

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

So I am new to the aggregation framework. I have a 2 collections with these documents:

**users**

```py
{
    '_id': ObjectId(user1),
    'name': 'Name1',
    'event': ObjectId(event1)
},
{
    '_id': ObjectId(user2),
    'name': 'Name2',
    'event': ObjectId(event2)
},
{
    '_id': ObjectId(user3),
    'name': 'Name3',
    'event': ObjectId(event1)
}
```

**events**

```py
{
    '_id': ObjectId(event1),
    'name': 'Event2',
    'type': 'Party'
},
{
    '_id': ObjectId(event2),
    'name': 'Event2',
    'type': 'Meeting'
}
```

**Expected Output**

```py
[
    {
    '_id': ObjectId(user1),
    'name': 'Name1',
    'event': 'Party'
    },
    {
    '_id': ObjectId(user2),
    'name': 'Name2',
    'event': 'Meeting'
    },
    {
    '_id': ObjectId(user3),
    'name': 'Name3',
    'event': 'Party'
    }

]
```

So as you can see, form the explanation above, I want to **group** users, and return users based on the event that they have attended.

**what I have done so far** (aggregating on users)

```py
[
    {
        "$lookup":
        {
            "from": "events",
            "localField": "event",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "Events"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$Events"
    },
    {
        "$group":
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "type": "$Events.type"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I am only getting the event documents. The output is:

```py
{ 'type':'Party'},
{'type': 'Meeting'}
```

> Can someone please guide me as to how you can group documents in collection by a field from a document in another collection?

Thankyou!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44042329/the-field-id-must-be-an-accumulator-object 
Try using `Events.type` - drop the `$`

Comment: That won't work. It'll just be considered as a string then. @DroidX86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$project` instead of `$group`:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "events",
            "localField": "event",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "Events"
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$Events"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            event: "$Events.name"
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following document can help you to solve your problem. Please refer the document--> [ref.Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)